# How do arrange divs into two rows of three columns, separated by even vs odd children?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with 6 children divs as follows

```
<div class="work-wrap">
   <div class="work-item">1</div>
   <div class="work-item">2</div>
   <div class="work-item">3</div>
   <div class="work-item">4</div>
   <div class="work-item">5</div>
   <div class="work-item">6</div>
</div>
```

I want to have a result like this

### 2    4   6

1   3    5

Comment: Use `nth-child(even)` and `nth-child(odd)` to select the different divs; and then just style them up how you wish.

Comment: What have you tried, if anything? Do you have any constraints? Libraries you're already using?

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate - though to be clear it takes *both* of the targets I listed to fully answer this one.

Comment: @TylerH This is definitely not a duplicate. Firstly, the second link is not the result though it shows how to split it, but the 1st link , there is no right answer at all and the bounty awarded answer is using `display: table`. I think you should re-consider this and open up this question for people to give a direct answer for this question.

Comment: @Gosi The bounty awarded answer is only one answer among *twenty-three* answers. Be sure to read all answers when looking at duplicate targets. As for reopening this -- there's no need, because it *is* a duplicate, and it already has answers, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a flexbox and change the order of the `:nth-child(odd)` items:

```css
.work-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.work-item {
  width: 33%;
}

.work-item:nth-child(odd) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-wrap">
  <div class="work-item">1</div>
  <div class="work-item">2</div>
  <div class="work-item">3</div>
  <div class="work-item">4</div>
  <div class="work-item">5</div>
  <div class="work-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I tried to implement this in my actual code, it forms just a single column instead of 3 columns

Comment: What is the width of the container?

Comment: I set it to 100%

Comment: Thanks, I added flex-direction: row

Answer (score 4):

You can leverage on `order` property in flex layouts:

```css
.work-wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.work-item:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

.work-item:nth-child(4) {
  order: 2;
}

.work-item:nth-child(6) {
  order: 3;
}

.work-item:nth-child(1) {
  order: 4;
}

.work-item:nth-child(3) {
  order: 5;
}

.work-item:nth-child(5) {
  order: 6;
}

.work-item {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="work-wrap">
   <div class="work-item">1</div>
   <div class="work-item">2</div>
   <div class="work-item">3</div>
   <div class="work-item">4</div>
   <div class="work-item">5</div>
   <div class="work-item">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have done a great job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use :nth-child() pseudo-class with flex-box layout, for example:

```
.work-wrap {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.work-item {
  order: 2;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
}
.work-item:nth-child(2n) {
  order: 1;
}
```